# JIT-optimized version of Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jit, vmware-workstation

I am not happy with the speed Eclipse runs inside my Windows XP VM (in VMWare). Do you know whether there is a JIT-optimized version of Eclipse that runs faster then the officially distributed one?

Update: Thank you @PterT, @Jörg and @maarons for pointing out my misconception. I am new to Java and so some terms may be still not very clear to me. In a recent question I asked about a CPU optimized for Java, one of the answers was that such CPU is not needed because

> Every commonly used JVM has a
>   sophisticated JIT compiler than
>   intelligently native-compiles methods
>   that would benefit from it. So
>   nowadays executing bytecode natively
>   is fairly useless.

Since I am new to Java, I thought perhaps I missed something important that makes it less CPU-hog than I currently experience. Are you saying that the only way to make Eclipse snappy is by running it on real hardware instead of inside a VM?

Comment: Surely since JIT optimization by definition happens at runtime, it's not a question of having a "JIT-optimized version".

Comment: +1 for this explanation. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly does this "CPU-hog" behaviour manifest?

Comment: @Thorbjørn It's sluggish and invoking the Android emulator takes **forever**.

Comment: that sounds more like memory-starved than CPU-hog, plus the Android emulator is large too.  Give your Windows as much RAM as you can live with, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question just doesn't make sense as JIT compilation is a property of JRE, not Eclipse.  You could try Zero and Shark enabled Icedtea, but I don't think it will be faster - your problem is probably running a resource eating application like Eclipse in a limited environment like a virtual machine.  Try running it without the virtualization layer if you need more speed.

Comment: +1 for this explanation. Thanks. What do you mean by "running it without the virtualization layer"?

Comment: Running it on your host system.  Unless you have really powerful hardware Eclipse will not offer satisfactory performance inside a virtual machine.

Comment: @maroons, not true.  The bottleneck is RAM and reasonable disk-I/O in the virtualization layer.  Eclipse use a LOT of small files all the time.

Comment: That depends on your hardware I think - for me CPU is almost always 100% when I try to run bigger programs in VM - could be different on CPU with virtualization extensions, but for me the bottleneck is definitely CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't make sense. It is simply impossible to download a JIT-optimized version of Eclipse, since the *very definition* of "JIT-optimized" is "optimized at runtime".

Comment: Three identical answers (well, one as a comment) and *I* am the only one who gets upvotes?

Comment: Well, my comment got equal upvotes at the time of writing... lesson learned for me is to post as 'answer' if I want the chance to gain rep.

Answer (score 0):

Give it more memory.  XP needs at least 1Gb for Eclipse to run well for any non-trivial load.

Comment: I have already given it 1GB RAM. I don't remember Visual Studio 6.0 for C++ being such a resource hog... Some folks claim that Java is fast. Of course it can be fast if: (1) You run it on the fastest hardware environment possible (2) Give it a lot of memory. But for me, it's like cheating.

Comment: Java _IS_ fast but at the expense of memory for JVM book keeping.  That is, however, not the problem with Eclipse.  It just has a _LOT_ of recordkeeping (the Ctrl-Space magic requires quite a bit) to do, and that takes memory.  Use Task Manager to see when Eclipse stops paging since that is most likely the situation you want to have.